# Unwanted list modification

Tags: c#, list, foreach, ilist, reference-type

I have an issue with trying to modify a list of Transactions within a foreach. I have created copies of the list passed into my method, made it read only, and yet when I try to change a value within any of the lists it changes that value within them all. Some type of memory link? I am unsure how to resolve this issue.

My program starts by declaring a class called Transaction (which is a generic class having Name, Value, Formatting), then I have subClasses :Transaction. I create a TransList (from public class TransList : IEnumerable) which has an object instance of each subClass. So a TransList would include a class named TranID, Amount, OrderID, Time, CardType, Comment1, Comment2. Each value of these subclasses could be string, decimal, DateTime. After that a list of  TransParts is created it is then put into a larger list called processTrans.

So Comment2 is the element with a payment citation number and if there is more than one number in there I want to separate that into more than one TransList add those new TransLists to processTrans and remove the non-separated one. From my code below, having tried every strategy, run-time modification occurs to not only the intended processTrans but also to tempProcessTrans, addOn, tran, tranPart.

If processTrans that is passed into method looks like this in the debugger locals
processTrans [0] _Items TranID.Value = SD234DF and Comment2 = adf;wer;
Then the output should be
processTrans [0] _Items TranID.Value = SD234DF-1 and Comment2.Value=adf
processTrans [1] _Items TranID.Value = SD234DF-2 and Comment2.Value=wer
I currently get
processTrans [0] _Items TranID.Value = SD234DF-1-2 and Comment2.Value=wer
processTrans [1] _Items TranID.Value = SD234DF-1-2 and Comment2.Value=wer

```
public static List<TransList> SeperateMultiCitations(List<TransList> processTrans) //change TransList seperating Multiple Citations
    {
        List<int> indexes=new List<int>();
        IList<TransList> tempProcessTrans = processTrans.AsReadOnly(); //this didn't help
        List<TransList> addOn= new List<TransList>(); //copy list didn't stop from changes to occur in processTrans at same time
        foreach (TransList tran in tempProcessTrans.ToList())
        {
            TransList copyTransList = tran;
            foreach (Transaction tranPart in tran.OfType<Comment2>())
            {
                if (new Regex(";.+;").IsMatch((string)tranPart.Value, 0))
                {
                    string[] citations = Regex.Split((string)tranPart.Value, ";").Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray();
                    int citNumb = 1;
                    indexes.Add(tempProcessTrans.IndexOf(tran));

                    foreach (string singleCitation in citations)
                    {
                        addOn.Add(ChangeTrans(tran, singleCitation, citNumb++)); when this line runs changes occur to all lists as well as trans, tranPart
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (int index in indexes.OrderByDescending(x => x))
        {
            processTrans.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        processTrans.AddRange(addOn);
        return processTrans;
    }
public static TransList ChangeTrans(TransList copyTransList, string singleCitation, int citNumb) //add ConFee
    {
        foreach (Transaction temp in copyTransList.OfType<TranID>())
        {
            temp.Value += "-" + citNumb;
        }
        foreach(Transaction temp in copyTransList.OfType<Comment2>())
        {
            temp.Value = singleCitation;
        }
        foreach (Transaction temp in copyTransList.OfType<Amount>())
        {
            //temp.Value = DboGrab(temp);
            //temp.Value = amount;
        }

        return copyTransList;
    }

public class Transaction : TranInterface
{
    public string Name;
    public object Value;
    public string Formating;

    public Transaction(string name, object value, string formating)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        Formating = formating;
    }
 }

 class TranID : Transaction
      {
          public TranID(string Name, string Value, string Formating) : base("Transaction ID",  Value, "@") { }
      }
 public class TransList : IEnumerable<Transaction> //not to add all the lengthy parts here but this just allows for adding the parts and iterating through them in the foreach statements
 {}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that constructs those objects and add them to the original list?

Comment: You aren't creating new instances of your objects so your modifications in ChangeTrans are occurring on the original class.  If I get your issue correct, when you process each item it will transform into one or more items based on the results of the regex?  If you restructure the question with more information about your structure, you might have better answers.

Comment: TransList copyTransList = tran; does not copy 'tran'. It only creates another reference to tran. You want a deepcopy. That's usually done by making a constructor that will take an object of it's own type and then copy all the values.

Comment: @MrFox - `trans` is a list here, good luck turning that into a struct.

Comment: @MrFox: even if you mean to change the `TransList` class to a `struct`, it is not true that value types "force deepcopy". "Deep copy" means that the entire object graph is replicated with newly allocated copies of the original members of the graph. A value type does get a shallow copy by default (while reference types don't even get that), but they do _not_ get a deep copy unless you write that yourself.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I don't mean turning the list into a struct but he objects in the list. So that would be the 'Transaction' class. Apologies for saying a struct forces deepcopy. Only the value (as in non-reference) properties in that class would be really copied instead of referenced.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen showed some of the code of the class types.

Comment: @MrFox I didn't realize making a new instance of an already created object instance only did a reference copy, and was struggling with trying to make a separated instance. This is a list not a struct and so is there a way of doing a true "deep" copy of the object list I already have created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is an inherent feature of [`reference types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/490f96s2(v=vs.100).aspx). When you call the `ChangeTrans()` method, the reference returned by that method is exactly the same as the one you passed in, which is that original value `tran`. Within the inner loop, the value of `tran` never changes, so on each iteration of the loop, you are modifying the same object over and over, adding it to your `addOn` list with each iteration.

This has two undesirable effects:

1. There is no difference between each element in the `addOn` list. They are all identical, referencing the same single object.
2. Any modification of any single element in the `addOn` list, or via the original reference to that single object, is visible via every other reference to that same single object. I.e. via all of the other elements in the list, and even that original reference in the `tran` variable (and of course, the `copyTranList` variable, which was assigned to the value of `tran`).

Without a more complete code example, it's not possible to know for sure what the best solution would be. However, one naïve solution would be to simply change your `ChangeTrans()` method so that it is responsible for making the new copy:

```
public static TransList ChangeTrans(
    TransList copyTransList, string singleCitation, int citNumb) //add ConFee
{
    TransList newTransList = new TransList();

    foreach (Transaction temp in copyTransList.OfType<TranID>())
    {
        Transaction newTransaction = new TranID();

        newTransaction.Value = temp.Value + "-" + citNumb;
        newTransList.Add(newTransaction);
    }
    foreach(Transaction temp in copyTransList.OfType<Comment2>())
    {
        Transaction newTransaction = new Comment2();

        newTransaction.Value = singleCitation;
        newTransList.Add(newTransaction);
    }

    return newTransList;
}
```

Note: I have no idea if the above actually would compile, or if it actually copies all of the values needed. I reiterate: since you have not shown the `TransList` or `Transaction` data structures, it's not possible to know what all in them needs to be copied, nor what the best way to copy those values would be.

That said, note in the above example that this version of the method:

1. Creates an entirely new instance of the `TransList` object, storing the reference in `newTransList`.
2. For each `Transaction` value to be modified, it creates an entirely new instance of `Transaction` (using the appropriate type), assigning to *that* instance's `Value` property the modified value.
3. For each of those new `Transaction` objects, it adds the object to the newly-created `TransList` object referenced by the `newTransList` variable.
4. Finally, it returns that newly-created `TransList` object, rather than the one that was passed to the method.

Presumably you know what the correct way to add `Transaction` elements to `TransList` object, as well as whether there are other members in a `Transaction` object that would need to be copied. The above is simply a basic illustration of where and how you can modify your code so that you do the "deep copy" needed to avoid the problem you're describing.

Comment: I do understand your answer, my question to this though is would I not then have two differing copies of say TranID within the TransList? And therefore need to remove the old one first.

Comment: Or rereading I think you are just having me create a whole new TransList within this method and then passing it back? Of course that being true I need to have every subclass of Transaction being created and added to the new TransList within here. Correct?

Comment: You do understand the example code I wrote. Unfortunately, your original code isn't complete enough for me to really understand what is actually needed. All I can say is that any object you want to be able to modify without affect the existing instances, you need to make a copy of the object before you modify it (or create a whole new one from scratch). You were adding the `TransList` object to a whole new list, which may or may not mean you need a whole new `TransList` object. Note if you don't create a new list, that means the new, modified objects will be added to your original `TransList`.